# How to practically calculate the accuracy of each class in muliclass classification problem?

Tags: classification, accuracy, precision-recall, multi-class, confusion-matrix

I have the following confusion matrix:

```
[[5584    0   11    6    6   24   27    3  262    0]
 [   0 6419   39   14    3   41    4    4  214    4]
 [  17   21 5287   67   59   19   48   34  402    4]
 [  20   13   95 5238    0  150   21   36  505   53]
 [   9   12   29    8 5245    6   26   13  384  110]
 [  21   15   21  127   45 4469   66   11  594   52]
 [  25   15   37    2   31   73 5566    6  163    0]
 [  18    9   43   13   37   12    4 5724  250  155]
 [  12   52   33   83    2  101   24    4 5509   31]
 [  19   18   25   51  102   25    1  147  517 5044]]
```

and I would like to calculate the accuracy of each class. I have found on the internet that it should be calculated as follows: `(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)` but when I try to implemented I basically get lost as I do not understand how to calculate any of the members except the `TP` which is the item on the diagonal.

I also thought to calculate it as the TP over the total number of times a class exists in the dataset (i.e. the row sum) but that would be equivalent to calculate the recall.

Would you be able to make a practical example on how to calculate the accuracy of class number 5 please?

This is what I tried so far in Python:

```
def accuracy_scores(confusion_matrix):
    msg = "accuracy\n\n"
    accuracies = []
    for i in range(confusion_matrix.shape[0]):
        tp = confusion_matrix[i][i]
        fn = sum(np.delete(confusion_matrix[i], i))
        fp = sum(np.delete(confusion_matrix[:, i], i))
        tn = sum(sum(np.delete(np.delete(confusion_matrix, i, 0), i, 1)))
        accuracy = (tp+tn)/(tp+  fn+  fp+  tn)
        accuracies.append(accuracy)
        msg += str(round(accuracy,2))+"\n"
    msg += f"accuracy avg: {round(np.mean(accuracies),2)}\n\n"
    return msg
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the accuracy of a class? Using MNIST handwritten digits as an example, do you mean how many times you were presented with a picture of a $2$ and classified it as a $2$, how many times the classifications of $2$ turned out to be true images of $2$ (not the same as the previous), or something else?

Comment: The first one you suggested thanks

Comment: How many times were you presented with a $2?$ of those, how many were identified as $2?$

Comment: How many times were you presented with a 2

Comment: In MNIST test data, there are about $6000$ such instances.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, using class number 5 as an example, just use take all the samples from class 5 as “positive” instance and all the other classes as “negative” instance, same for predictions. Just keep in mind that accuracy is [not the best metric and can be misleading for unbalanced classes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/35989), what would be the case for multi-class classification data if you look only on the true vs not-true pairs.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Could you make a numerical example with the confusion matrix I provided please?